# Android Theme Style Programmatically

Tags: java, android, styles, themes

After watching this video I got a good idea for designing my own Popup Boxes

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fn5OlqQuOCk

The pain is I need to add Theme Style in XML,
Set this as theme in manifest
Then add in Java Activity

So I was searching if there is way to modify Themes programmatically instead of putting in XML.
So I can copy single Java file to all my projects instead of adding in 3 places.

```
<style name="AppTheme.MsgBoxSreen" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>

There is only setTheme(R.style. MsgBoxSreen) option and nothing else
```

Kindly help me to do this programmatically.
I am sure there must be a way.